# Can Google Cloud Platform preemptive instances be re-started automaticaly?

Tags: cloud, platform, preemptive

I beleived that Google Cloud Platform preemptive instances were restarted automaticaly when the engine releases the ressource but I was wrong.

Once preempted the instance seems to need a manual restart.

Is there a way to restart the instance automaticaly after preemption ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can instance status periodically and restart it if it was terminated. Assuming instance name `instance1` and period 5 minutes it will be something like this:

```
while true 
do
    status=`gcloud compute instances list --filter name=instance1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'`
    [[ $status == TERMINATED ]] && gcloud compute instances start instance1
    sleep 300
done
```

Comment: Thank you but where from do you exec this script ?

Comment: From any host that has API access. For personal projects this is my workstation, for business projects certain (non preemptive) instance in the cloud.